# C++ Problem with overriding base class variable

Tags: c++, oop

I have 3 classes that derive from each other:

```cpp
class Shape
{
public:
    float r;
};

class ThreeDimentional : public Shape
{
public:
    virtual float area() = 0;
    virtual float volume() = 0;
};

class Sphere : public ThreeDimentional
{
public:
    float r;

    float area() {
        return 4*pi*pow(r, 2);
    }

    float volume() {
        return float(4)/3*pi*pow(r, 3);
    }
};
```

In `main`, I create an instance pointer of `ThreeDimentional` and set its value with a `Sphere`.
And then change its `r` to 2. I think it somehow changes `r` of the base class? because it returns the volume as 0. Isn't sphere supposed to override the `r` of base class? how can I change r of sphere?

```cpp
int main()
{
    ThreeDimentional* s1 = new Sphere;
    s1->r = 2;
    cout << s1->volume() << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0
```

Comment: You don't (and shouldn't) 'inherit' variables (in fact, what you're doing, as you have discovered, is duplicating it).  So just remove `float r;` from `Sphere` and see where it leads.

Comment: No, there are 2 different member variables named `r`. The variable you write is the one of the `Shape` part of the sphere, but the one your overload of `volume` reads is the one of `Sphere`...

Comment: @Paul Sanders
I get this error when I remove `r`.
uselessapp.cpp: In function 'int main()':
uselessapp.cpp:128:9: error: 'class ThreeDimentional' has no member named 'r'
     s1->r = 2;
         ^

Comment: @Parsa A radius is a property that makes sense only for some kinds of objects. What would be the meaning of the radius for a cube?

Comment: @Parsa _I get this error when I remove r_ [cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n2ve07EIkZbrWvY2).  Did you remove the right one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override data members. You can override only virtual member functions.

If every `Shape` is supposed to have a radius, then `Sphere` shouldn't declare another `r` (which will just hide the one in `Shape` depending on the context from where it is named).

If only a `Sphere` is supposed to have a radius, then it shouldn't be possible to set `r` through a `ThreeDimentional` pointer, which ought to be agnostic about what kind of `ThreeDimentional` object the pointer is pointing to. (In circumstances where a decision must still be taken based on the derived type nonetheless, `dynamic_cast` can be used.)

Which of the two applies depends on your intended interpretation for "radius"/`r`, but typically only spheres have a radius in the strict sense.